# Render Subdocuments through Template

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document RFQ and a subdocument materials with 4 fields and the possibility of having a lengthy list of materials. How would I ideally display the subdocument materials in a table ?

```
{

  "_id" : 1,

  "sdate" : ISODate("1924-12-03T05:00:00Z"),
  "adate" : ISODate("2007-03-17T04:00:00Z"),

  "materials" : [
              {
                "award" : "W.W. McDowellAward",
                "year" : 1967,
                "by" : "IEEE Computer Society"
              },
              {
                "award" : "National Medal of Science",
                "year" : 1975,
                "by" : "National Science Foundation"
              },
              {
                "award" : "Turing Award",
                "year" : 1977,
                "by" : "ACM"
              },
              {
                "award" : "Draper Prize",
                "year" : 1993,
                "by" : "National Academy of Engineering"
              }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post your collection schema.

Comment: Hi , I just edited to add the collection scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about displaying each subdocument in separate table-like structure?

Like this:

```
 Template.hello.coll = function () {
    return Coll.find({});
 };
```

And in your html, the subdocuments can be displayed with something like:

`{{#each this.materials}}` within the main `{{#each}}` helper.

```
      {{#each coll}}
        <tr>
            <td> {{sdate}} </td>
            <td> {{adate}} </td>

            {{#each this.materials}}
            <tr>
                <td>  {{award}}  </td>
                <td>  {{year}}  </td>
                <td>  {{by}}  </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
```